# PS4 Game sharing shared game

Tags: ps4

Lets say that FRIEND_1 is sharing his account with FRIEND_2 and FRIEND_2 has now full access to all downloads of FRIEND_1.

The question is, can FRIEND_2 share his account with FRIEND_3 so that FRIEND_3 can download the games from FRIEND_1?

Comment: doesn't seem to be the case but i have no means to test this in order to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Game Sharing on the PS4 is typically done by logging in to a friend's PS4, then using the settings to "Set this PS4 as my Primary PS4", which allows any user signed into that PS4 to access your library. Only one console can be your primary PS4.

To reword, you don't share the games with a *friend*, you share them with a PS4 *console* that your friend logs in to.

To use your example, if FRIEND_1 "game shared" with FRIEND_2's PS4, FRIEND_2 could access all of FRIEND_1's games on their console. If FRIEND_2 "game shared" with FRIEND_3's console, then FRIEND_3 could **only** access games that FRIEND_2 (and FRIEND_3, of course) owned. This does **not** allow FRIEND_3 to access FRIEND_1's games, as FRIEND_1's games are only shared with FRIEND_2's console.

Imagine the possibilities if this were possible - one "Master" account could allow everyone in the world to share games by constantly sharing from one account to another. Sony would shut it down pretty quick.